# Working with the operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

I was reading Narasimhan's Complex Analysis book, and in the part where he explains the maximum modulus principle, he introduces two operators $\Delta u=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 x}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 y}$ and $\Delta^c u=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}}$ (which is actually just $\Delta^c=\frac{1}{4}\Delta$, really) and goes like...

> If $u(z)=|f(z)|^2=f(z)\overline{f(z)}$, we have $$\Delta u=4\Delta^c u=4\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\cdot\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial \bar{z}}=4|f'(z)|^2 \geq 0.$$

and this is essentially the whole content of the proof.

Now, my question is, how does one get the expression $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\cdot\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial \bar{z}}$ so quickly from $\Delta^c u$?

For me, the only way to prove this is to plug in all the $\partial x$'s and $\partial y$'s according to the definitions of $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}$ and see where the tedious calculation leads. But since the proof is so short, I guess there is some other way to see this in a very simple manner. So... How??

Comment: Is $f$ holomorphic? If so then I think this follows from the product rule for these operators.

Comment: @user71352: Yes, $f$ is holomorphic here. Could you explain me the product rule in more details?

Comment: $f$ have $z$'s and $\bar{f}$ have $\bar{z}$'s so $$u_{z\bar{z}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(f.\frac{\partial\bar{f}}{partial\bar{z}})=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial\bar{f}}{partial\bar{z}}$$

Comment: @Dilemian The product rule is:

$\frac{\partial\left(fg\right)}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}g+f\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}$

with a similar rule for $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}$. These operators also commute when $f$ has sufficient smoothness (you don't have to worry about this since $f$ is holomorphic). You should also note that

$\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial z}=\bar{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}}$,

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=\bar{\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial z}}$,

and

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0$

Comment: Note that the last equation given follows from the Cauchy-Riemann equations and the previous two equations follow from computing these operators on the real and imaginary parts of $f$. It may be helpful to read about Wirtinger derivatives: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives

Comment: @user71352: Thank you. I will go through the identities you've explained.

Comment: @Dilemian No problem.